# fake profiles - Is it forbidden to create one?

Tags: names

Fake profiles are a huge problem in online world. Even in this forum, there are people who use fake profiles, so we are not able to guess their religion. I know pet name is allowed but there should a way to know the real  name.

I am asking the Islamic perspective, not the forum rules.

Comment: What does "fake" mean in this context? Is my profile "fake" when goldPseudo is (obviously?) not my birth name, even though it is very much the same online identity I use elsewhere?

Comment: بِئْسَ الاسْمُ الْفُسُوقُ بَعْدَ الإيمَانِ we cannot call ourselves bad names. goldPseudo seems to be fake name to me. Actual Gold is the good one. Actually this question is general, not meant for anyone in particular. I said only because you asked.